# Eddystone UID in Javascript

Tags: javascript, cordova, uid, beacon, eddystone

I am trying to make an app using eddystone UID. I achieved to detect URL, but I cannot detect the UID.
I tried Cordova : https://github.com/evothings/cordova-eddystone
I have an estimate that is "sending" its UID.
But I do not see How can I detect it and just display the beacon with its UID.
I have seen many things in java or in other languages, but I would like to do it with cordova in javascript.
Thank you very much

Comment: Are you doing this on iOS or Android?

Comment: I am doing this on Android

Comment: I followed this : https://evothings.com/detecting-eddystone-beacons-in-javascript-made-easy/

Comment: But I do not want to find the URL but the UID. I have an estimate that only broadcasts the UID.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Eddystone Javascript find UID](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/34198803/eddystone-javascript-find-uid)