# Eddystone Javascript find UID

Tags: javascript, android, uid, beacon, eddystone

I am trying to build an android app in js that can detect eddystone beacons emitting UID.
I followed this : https://evothings.com/detecting-eddystone-beacons-in-javascript-made-easy/

But I can only detect beacon html.

I cannot find the line where you can look for UID. 
Does anyone has an idea ?

Comment: To be able to give a qualified response you need to describe what beacon you are using. Is it a hardware beacon? What brand?

Answer (score 0):

Are you sure your beacon is set to broadcast the Eddystone-UID packet?

The thing to keep in mind is, Eddystone-UID and Eddystone-URL are two completely separate types of packets, and your beacon might only be able to broadcast one at a time.

Check with your beacon's vendor how to set it to broadcast the Eddystone-UID packet.

The Evothings PhoneGap plugin you're using returns both Eddystone-URL and Eddystone-UID packets it found, through a single [success callback](https://github.com/evothings/cordova-eddystone#scan-for-beacons). The example app from the tutorial you've linked to then takes the beacon, figures out if its URL or UID (or both), and only [shows what's available](https://github.com/evothings/cordova-eddystone/blob/master/example/index.html#L140).

Comment: Yes I am sure that i do it.